# class is getting triggered repeatedly onScroll

Tags: javascript, css, classname, onscroll

I have an onscroll function where a class is added to my header once you scroll down the page and back to its original state once you are at the top. Now, the function works perfectly but it's repeatedly querying the DOM. So if I scroll down, the class of "setOpaqueState" is repeatedly injected as so:

```
<div id="header1" class="setOpaqueState setOpaqueState setOpaqueState setOpaqueState"/>
```

and even while scrolling towards the top, it'll keep adding it until i reach the top and that's when "removeOpaqueState" will get added.

I'v tried using window.scroll=null; at the end of my function but that just keeps my header with the class of "setOpaqueState" throughout.

Here is my JS:
    window.onscroll = scroll;

```
function scroll() {
    var header=document.getElementById("header1");

    if((document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset) > 50){
        header.className = header.className.replace ( /(?:^|\s)removeOpaqueState(?!\S)/g , '' );
        header.className += " setOpaqueState";
    }
    else {
        header.className = header.className.replace ( /(?:^|\s)setOpaqueState(?!\S)/g , '' ); /* REGEX-verify the above is the whole classname/ensures there is no non-space character following*/
        header.className += " removeOpaqueState";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a class `removeOpaqueState`? Can't you just put these styles by default on `#header1`? `if(offset>50){header.className="setOpaqueState";} else {header.className="";}`

Comment: removeOpaqueState has a transparency of 50%. When you load the page, the header is transparent and once you scroll down, its changes to opaque and back to transparent once you're at the top. Only applies to one page, rest of the other pages are opaque by default

Comment: ok, then would this do what you want? `var default="myClass"; if(offset>50){header.className=default+" setOpaqueState";} else {header.className=default+" removeOpaqueState";}`

Comment: implementing that does not trigger my onScroll function...Before I used classList.add/"".remove and worked perfectly but unfortunately IE10 & below does not support it so had to use className.